# native facebook application code

Tags: android, facebook

I am looking for a native facebook application for android application. I need to display all the feeds that has been posted in my account.

Sample example code shall be useful.

Looking forward for your response.

Comment: check out [facebook-android-sdk](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at this example, this may help you.

http://www.integratingstuff.com/2010/10/14/integrating-facebook-into-an-android-application/

Comment: At this link there is a complete step-by-step procedure, you need to follow.